# Instantiation of function templates

Tags: c++, templates, explicit-instantiation

In the following program we take the address of a function template for which no definition is available.

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T);

int main()
{
    void (*funptr)(int) = fun;
}
```

I was taught that the compiler decides to instantiate a function template when its address is taken, but the above program compiles just fine (of course the linker will throw an error that it cannot find the definition for `fun`). Compilation only fails if we use explicit instantiation:

```
template <typename T>
void fun(T);

template void fun<int>(int);

int main()
{}
```

Does this mean that only compiling the second source code instantiates the function template? Or is it also instantiated in the first but I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you take an address or call the function, the compiler leaves a reference to its instantiation. If there was the template definition, it would've been instantiated to satisfy that reference. But since the template definition is not provided, it cannot be actually instantiated, so only the unresolved reference is left. That unresolved reference must be resolved at the linking stage by a different object file, which contains the necessary instantiation. This means that the instantiation must have happened when that other object file was compiled.

When you explicitly instantiate the function template, the template definition [must be present](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.explicit#7.sentence-2) (otherwise, there's nothing to instantiate). Since you haven't provided one, you get an error at the compilation stage, rather than linking.

Comment: Not really, as it does not mention function templates.

Comment: Oh yeah it says class templates sorry

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.inst#9 then? Says only the declaration is instantiated anyway.

Comment: Seems closer, but taking address of a function does not involve overload resolution. This may be inaccurate wording in the standard. In any case, the logic with non-template functions applies here as well - it is enough to have a function declaration to be able to take its address or invoke it. It just means the function has to be defined in another translation unit.

Comment: How do you take the address of a function without performing overload resolution? Which address do you get then, when there are multiple overloads?

Comment: If you're going to point out that you can take the address of a function and _then_ use a cast to disambiguate between overloads, don't, because that's [a rare instance of C++ working backwards](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#6) ;)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see how it is backwards. The cast defines the target type, according to which the function overload is picked. http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#1 defines other ways to specify the target type and http://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#2 says there can be no target (which is basically only possible when there is only one function under a given name). I guess, you could say in the latter case that technically overload resolution is still performed, though it is trivial.

Comment: I think, http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.over#5 supports the first paragraph of my answer, though, again, it doesn't mention taking address of the function.

Comment: It's backwards because in no other context is an expression's evaluation (e.g. which overload is picked by `&func`) decided by what's destined to happen to its result (e.g. casting that pointer to a particular type). This is a deliberate exception in C++ because there's not really any other way to deal with pointers to overloaded functions. I believe the wording actually used to say this explicitly but it seems to have been neutered at some point.

Comment: The way I see it, the function name alone is a reference (not in C++ meaning, as a general term) to a function or a set of functions. Much like a variable name is a reference (again, a general term) to an object. The context of the function name defines which particular function is used and in which way. Same with variables - it is the context, what defines what happens with the variable (e.g. are you binding a reference to it, taking its address, loading or storing a value, etc.) A name in a C++ program simply identifies an entity (or a set of entities, in case of function overloads).

Comment: Function overloads are special only in that the overload set is not a representable entity in C++, so there are special rules that prohibit operating on the set other than selecting a single function from the set. These rules are what overload resolution is.

Comment: That's another way of looking at it, yes